# forwarding a URI to a local server

Tags: windows, uri

After reading [Registering an Application to a URI Scheme](http://alifeofproductivity.com/exactly-how-long-your-work-breaks-should-be/?source=newsletter) about how to register an application in Windows to respond to a certain URI scheme, I was wondering if this can be done, but instead of an application, have a localhost server handle the calls.

Can I add a localhost URL to a HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT command parameter? Are only .exe allowed there?

EDIT: I've tried this with localhost, unfortunately it doesn't have any effect.

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Heh, after placing a bounty I've realized how to set a localhost URL as an application registered for a URI scheme.

For example for a SIP address call the open command would be:

```
[HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT\sip\shell\open\command] @="explorer \"http://localhost:8000/%1\""
```

This way we use the **explorer** command to open up the localhost URL that uses the first parameter as the SIP address to call